# I need the code to control the duration of my toast in android

Tags: android

I want the code that allows freedom of duration of the toast.

also the location of a toast. i tried using handlers but im not completely sure how it works so that was a failure from my side.

so any better ideas?

Comment: i guess you could provide duration value as milliseconds like 3000 for 3 seconds

Answer (score 3):

```
public void CustomToast(Context context, String msg, long timeinmillisec) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, ""+msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeinmillisec, 1000)     {

        private boolean isShowing = false;

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (isShowing) {
                toast.cancel();
            } else {
                toast.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
    countDownTimer.start();
}
```

Comment: Just tried and this does not work, besides the positioning of the toast. Where did you get this code?

Comment: That's mine and works well as i am using it. Although i have used custom layout to customize toast.

Comment: The only thing you have change in duration is the from LENGTH_SHORT to LENGTH_LONG, which is 1.5 seconds to 2.5 seconds. The onTick has no effect on toast.show() for me at all, and I am implementing it exactly as you are. Perhaps you could show how you're calling this method to display the parsed msg.

Comment: I retract my statement, you're code works providing it is implemented correctly.

Comment: oh i got it....fixed it now ,forgot to set the text message on it,glad that helped.

Comment: I revised it a little as well in my own answer plus displayed how to call and utilise. Giving yours a +1

Answer (score 1):

As for the location, you can call the following method of Toast class.
**setGravity (int gravity, int xOffset, int yOffset)**

You can only set the duration to one of the following constants **LENGTH_SHORT** and 
**LENGTH_LONG**

Comment: Doesn't work @Kushtrim, those duration are are default set. i want to customize them.

Comment: You cannot. If you want shorter durations, you might have to use some custom dialog. For longer durations, a *workaround* is to call Toast multiple times with the same text ( though it may  blink transitioning from Toast to Toast )